# Android JobService being stopped for no apparent reason

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I have a JobService that starts a thread and does some long-running synchronisation with a server. The synchronisation could actually last an hour or more. The Job is scheduled to start when the phone is charging and should restart every hour:

```
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceName)
        .setRequiresCharging(true)
        .setOverrideDeadline(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        .build();
```

So, I plug my Android 7 phone and observe the logs. I can see clearly that every 10 minutes or so the job is stopped by the scheduler (the `onStopJob()` is called) and then restarted.

Why is the scheduler stopping my job even if the phone is plugged?

I have checked if there are memory leaks, but it seems that it's not the case.

Help !

Comment: They don't want runaway jobs, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

According to [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630606/how-long-is-the-jobservice-execution-time-limit-mentioned-in-androids-jobinte) there is indeed a limit of 10 minutes maximum execution.